# Error from typedef struct

Tags: c++, struct, typedef

The following code causes several errors

```
typedef struct
{
    char name[20];
    int vertices_qty;
    int polygons_qty;
    Vector3D vertex[MAX_VERTICES];
    Triangle polygon[MAX_POLYGONS];
    TexCoord mapcoord[MAX_VERTICES];
    int id_texture;
    obj_type, *obj_type_ptr;
}
```

specifically the last line:

```
obj_type, *obj_type_ptr;
```

when I hover over `obj_type` with the mouse it reads:

> this declaration has no storage class or type specifier

there's also a warning that reads:

> untagged 'struct' declared, no symbols

all of this is within a `commons.h` header file that defines several stucts such as `vector2d`, `vector3d`, `material`, etc, etc for a program that uses openGL

what do I need to do to make the error go away?

Comment: Maybe get rid of `typedef struct` and instead use `struct Your_Name`?  The `typedef struct` is a holdover from `C` and is not necessary in `C++`.

Comment: Move that curly brace up one line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably want

```
typedef struct
{
    char name[20];
    int vertices_qty;
    int polygons_qty;
    Vector3D vertex[MAX_VERTICES];
    Triangle polygon[MAX_POLYGONS];
    TexCoord mapcoord[MAX_VERTICES];
    int id_texture;
}   obj_type, *obj_type_ptr;
```

as the `obj_type` and `obj_type_ptr` are the new types and they have to be specified after the closing bracket of `typedef struct{...} TYPE_HERE;`. Note that in C++ you don't need a `typedef`, you can simply define

```
struct obj_type{...};
```

then use it as is

```
obj_type foo;  // object of type obj_type
obj_type* foo_ptr; // pointer to obj_type
```

Comment: It would be an improvment to your question if you specify the real problem in the code too beside the solution (Beside that, nice and fast answer).

Answer (score 2):

Simply give the last two a valid type. The error means, that you specified a variable which hasn't a *existing type* or hasn't *any type* specified.
So, according to your solution:

```
typedef struct
{
    char name[20];
    int vertices_qty;
    int polygons_qty;
    Vector3D vertex[MAX_VERTICES];
    Triangle polygon[MAX_POLYGONS];
    TexCoord mapcoord[MAX_VERTICES];
    int id_texture; //Fine until the next line
    obj_type, *obj_type_ptr; //Compiler says: "Where is the type D:?"
}
```

Simply declare the types before your struct(don't know which exactly you meant):

```
struct obj_type{...}//I'm a nice struct
```

And change your struct to that:

```
 typedef struct
{
    char name[20];
    int vertices_qty;
    int polygons_qty;
    Vector3D vertex[MAX_VERTICES];
    Triangle polygon[MAX_POLYGONS];
    TexCoord mapcoord[MAX_VERTICES];
    int id_texture;
    obj_type *obj_type_ptr; //Now it's correct
}
```